# IDLE can't import Tkinter. Your Python may not be configured for Tk

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-3.x, tkinter

I am running Ubuntu 10.10, and I installed Python 3.2 today. The system is already running Python 2.6.

I typed idle3.2 in the terminal and it gave me:

> IDLE can't import Tkinter. Your Python may not be configured for Tk.

So I searched on *Stack Overflow* (and in some other places) for a solution, I installed `python-tk`, I rechecked that I have `tclsh` on the system, but I still can't manage to open `idle3.2`.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

On OSX, this can be resolved with macports by installing the python tkinter package for your python version. In my case, with python 2.7, I ran on the terminal:

```
sudo port install py27-tkinter
```

change the "27" to your python version number.

Comment: How can I do this, if I don't have sudo rights? Thanks.

Comment: Don't forgot that if you are using TKinter, you will require an X11 server as well. XQuartz (X11 for Mac OS) is also in MacPorts as the xorg-server.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install idle
```

Choose one from

- idle
- idle3
- idle-python2.6
- idle-python2.7
- idle-python3.1
- idle-python3.2

for your python version.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the version between python and idle not matching.
U can check your python version by typing : python
Then sudo aptget install the right idle version same with your python version

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error message when installing python3.4 on Fedora 20. The problem was that tk-devel was not installed during the python configure/make. The explicit steps to do this correctly are

download and extract python3.4 from python.org https://www.python.org/downloads/

Find and install the right tkinter and tk-devel:

yum search tkinter

yum install python3-tkinter-3.3.2-17.fc20.x86_64

yum search tk-devel

yum install tk-devel.x86_64

AFTER these are onboard, cd into the python3.4 package directory and run the configure; make, make install process.

I spent too much time resolving this issue. Hopefully this post will help may others to a quick resolution.

PS stackoverflow is awesome. If google brought you to this article, spend some time and surf around the site.

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted.  Worked for me on Scientific Linux 6.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed python-tk and the system is running python 2.6 then it is most likely that  you installed Tkinter for python 2.6. Try installing python3-tk.

Answer (score 1):

you need to install tk or tk-dev packages for ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

On my arch linux system I had the same problem easily solved by typing

```
yaourt tkinter
```

and installing the first package `community/python-pmw 2.0.1-2 [installed]`

Answer (score 0):

Type "idle-python2.6" in the terminal..it worked for me

Comment: Please include an explanation supporting your answer.

Comment: That might be the case for a very particular combination of Python and an OS. If tkinter is not installed, it will fail anyway.