# Python 2.7.10_2: No module named _tkinter

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, tkinter

I've written a Python script using tkinter. However today, after updating `homebrew`, I'm getting the following error:

> No module named _tkinter

when I try to import tkinter.

Interactive terminal looks like this:

```
>>> import Tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/
python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py"line 39, in <module>
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named _tkinter
>>>
```

When I try to import `_tkinter` I get this:

```
ImportError: No module named _tkinter
```

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: How do I fix the error? @Alejandro

Comment: Check these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459444/tkinter-python-may-not-be-configured-for-tk, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320954/idle-cant-import-tkinter-your-python-may-not-be-configured-for-tk. When you have a specific error or exception like this, you should copy exactly the key part of the traceback, in this case `ImportError: No module named _tkinter`, and past it on google search box, and then click `Google Search`
, and usually you are lucky ;)

Answer (score -3):

Well Tkinter is the GUI library that comes in python as default. If you can't call Tkinter that means your python installation is corrupted. Re-installing your python should fix it.

Comment: I believe the default OS X Python doesn't include Tkinter?

Comment: I don't think so. Check this out [Wiki Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tkinter) Tkinter is included in Windows & mac installation of python.

Comment: Should have mentioned I've already tried that several times, without any luck.

Comment: @Kupiakos The default Python distribution for Mac OS X includes tkinter!